# Python sockets: How to handle many clients connecting to one server?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, sockets

I am trying create a server-client-network with up to 200 clients connecting to one server. The part that worries me is, that the Server has to handle up to 200 connections:

```
# creating a server socket
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), PORT))
server.listen()
# allowing clients to connect
while True:
    client, addr = server.accept()
    print(addr, "has connected !")
    # handle each client in its own thread
    t = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client,), daemon=True)
    t.start()
```

Having up to 200 clients, will create up to 200 Threads. My gut is telling me: "that is to much". So the first question is, should one create a newtwork with a single server and over 100 clients ? And the second question is: Is there a good way to handle such a situation ?

Comment: You can use async or tasks
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#tcp-echo-server
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#awaitables

No need to create hundreds of memory-hungry threads.

Comment: 200 threads is nothing. 200,000 might be cause for concern, depending on your hardware. For clients in the hundreds, keep it simple and stick with threads.